regex matching first numeric second alpha third numeric fourth numeric
I need a regex for the following pattern:

Total of 4 characters (numeric, alphabet, numeric, numeric).
first character must be a number(0-9)
second character must be an alphabet(A-M, I should be excluded) -> this refers to months January to December
third and fourth characters must be a number(0-9) -> Date

Examples:

3K01 is valid
3K40 is invalid
5I01 is invalid -> A-M
1A01 is valid

Dim validateLot As String = "/^((0?[1-9]|1[012])M|(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])D)$/"
 
Dim r As New Regex(validateLot)
    
If (r.IsMatch(txtCarton0.Text)) Then
Else
End If


Why does your regex has ending characters M or D? And why does it only match three characters, with a digit at the second position?? This seems nothing like what you want to test. Can you show your real effort to write a regex? This looks like you just copied a random regex and pasted it here.

Do you have to use a regex? If the third and fourth characters represent a day of the month, how are you intending to handle 29 February in leap years when there does not appear to be a year in the string?

If "second character must be a number(A-M i should not come)" is to mean "second character is an uppercase letter between 'A' and 'H', inclusive, or between 'J' and 'M', inclusive", you should write the latter or something similar (before stating that it specifies a month). Consider also writing "a digit" where you have "a number" and clarify that the last two characters are to be "01" to "31", an imperfect representation of the day of month. It appears to merely test if the string is valid you want ^\d[A-HJ-Z](?:0[1-9]\d|[12]\d|3[01])$. Demo

So, there are 4 characters, numeric, alpha, numeric, numeric.
They represent as follows:

first character must be a number(0-9) ≡ regex: \d or [0-9]
second character must be a letter between A-M, without I ≡ regex: [A-HJ-M]
third & fourth characters are represents Calendar Date (01-31)

  Date: 
      01-09: ([0][1-9])
      10-29: ([1-2][0-9])
      30-31: ([3][0-1])

So, third & fourth character matching regex: (([0][1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))

Therefore your regex should be:
^[0-9][A-HJ-M](([0][1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))$
or
^\d[A-HJ-M](([0][1-9])|([1-2]\d)|([3][0-1]))$

Test regex: https://regex101.com/r/7AImf2/1
Thank You

Is this what you need
@"(?=.{4})((?=.{2}3[01])|(?=.{2}[0-2]\d))^[0-9][^IN-Z\d][0-3][0-9]$"gm

https://regex101.com/r/4Y9fcU/1

If using lookarounds you might consider ^(?!..(?:00|3[2-9]))\d[A-HJ-M][0-3]\d$ Demo
